# How to have multiple values to 1 select option?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I want my select `option` to change 2 things: an image and a price. However, since there can only be 1 option `value`, only one of the jQuery will work. How do I have more than 1 value in `option`? If it can't be done, what is a solution?

HTML:

```
<select id="panelfabric" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="$168">Normal</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
// select panel image
$('#panelfabric').on('change', function() {
  $('#imageToSwap2').prop('src', 
    ['img/panel/', $('#panelfabric').val(), '.png'].join('')    
    );
});

// select panel price
$('#panelfabric').on('change', function () {
  $('#priceToSwap2').text($(this).val()
    );
});
```

P.S. I can't name the image $168.png so that will not be a solution.

Comment: you could have a comma delimited value, with a single on 'change'.

Comment: I use something like `<option value="$168|png">`

Comment: `<option value="$168" data-img-src="the-costly-one.png">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to attach as many pieces of information as you need to the `<option>` using HTML5 data attributes:

```
<option value="whatever" data-price="$168" data-image="http://...">
    Normal
</option>
```

And then:

```
$('#panelfabric').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#panelfabric').children(":selected");

  $('#imageToSwap2').prop('src', $selected.data("image"));
  $('#priceToSwap2').text($selected.data("price"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Jon's `data-XXX` solution. Another option is to put a mapping table in your Javascript:

```
var item_data = {
    "whatever": { price: 168, image: "http://..." },
    "something": { price: 200, image: "http://..." },
    ... };
```

and then:

```
$("#panelfabric").on("change", function() {
    var item = $(this).val();
    $('#imageToSwap2').prop('src', item_data[item].image);
    $('#priceToSwap2').text('$'+item_data[item].price);
});
```